# how to run two or more threads at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading

i'm working on a project for the college i was asked to code a program that cracks the password.

the program input is the length of the password and the username, the program just works fine when the key is less than 5 chars but when the length increases to 6 the time to crack the password will be 8 minutes and 38 seconds.

so i was asked to crack password in real time and make the good use of multi-core processor

Threads run in parallel but just one thread at a time , so how to run more than a thread at a time?

Comment: Try System.out.println(array1);

Comment: Please explain more clearly what you mean. Hint: What is the opposite of multiplication?

Comment: Basicly, you have **a * b = c**, you know b and c ... And you want to find a. Basic math ... then you repeat this for an array

Comment: The operation array1*array2=array3 is not defined mathematically. I would not know what you mean with this unless you define it. I have neither heard of array inverse, but this should not be too unexpected due to the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

example for this:

```
double[] arr1=new double[3];
double[] arr2={5,8,17};
double[] arr3={46,47,102};
for(int i=0;i<arr3.length;i++){
    arr1[i]=arr3[i]/arr2[i];
}
for(double i:arr1){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Why people would stop asking "stupid" question if there is always someone answering them ... it's easier for them to ask without trying by themself

Comment: you want me to stop answering questions? i bet there was a time you would have asked similar questions. maybe not here but somewhere

Comment: Yes, stop answering bad question. And no, I never ask those kind of question simply because I always take time to understand, analyse, debug my code. Even when I was a newbie... Here, OP ask to find a solution to the question a teacher probably gave him...

Comment: @AxelH people do so in hope of reputation .

Comment: @XtremeBaumer the problem is not that the question would be "stupid". The problem is that the OP is lazily formulated by not giving a proper problem formulation. An unexperienced person would likely ask "stupid" questions, but if these are formulated in a good way they may be of more help than the "advanced" questions.

Comment: @TilakMadichetti unfortunalty, I know...

Comment: i don't care much about reputation. i am just bored and for me i find answering any questions here a practice in coding since sometimes people can improve my code.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer you can feel free to fork some github projects - that'll be the best practice or go go to code ground stack community XD